# How to passing namespace as a parameters to a memeber function and use this namespace's data type?

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ shared lib in ubuntu env, one class in this lib let's call it `NLP` need use user selected model let's call it `Model_i`, but because I am using some third party libraries, I defined data type inside the `Model_i` class, like:

```
using spline_model_i = xxx::T<const, const>;
```

but in `NLP` class I need use this `spline_model_i` for this model, one method I was thought is passing the namespace to `NLP` class, so I can do this `Model_i_ns::spline_model_i`, then how can I passing a string which is actually a namespace type and convert it back and use it in the `NLP` class ?

-- Thanks

Comment: You can't "pass " a namespace anywhere. It is also unclear both what the problem is, and what your proposed solution is. Please explain with a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a namespace. But since "use their data type" is a part of the question (the one and only that is clear), I'd say you can use a class instead:

```
template <typename T>
void do_stuff(const T& t)
{
  using data_type = typename T::data_type;
  // do whatever you want
}

// example struct
struct your_namespace_imitation
{
  using data_type = int;
};

template <typename B>
class A
{
public:
  void do_stuff(const typename B::data_type&);
};
```

Comment: Thank u friend ! it's a clever way, a minor question is: if I need use a data type defined in class B in class A's function A::fa() {//class B's Type}, so the scope of this data type is only alive in function A::fa() right? I cannot use it some other functions in class A.

Comment: you can legally use `B`'s type anywhare you want. Though it will introduce a dependency on `B`. Also if you have a class template `template <typename B> class A{};`, then ` B` and its types will be visible everywhere inside `A` (`B` is a template parameter here).

Comment: I think I made it, just use a struct, so all members can use it, thank u !

Comment: @JetLee I suggest you clarify what you wanted in your question, since it is hard to understand. This site is useful for people who look for solutions for similar problems. And it is hard to find out the similarity if the question is not clear